# Enabling ARC on Phonegap iOS project

Tags: ios, cordova, automatic-ref-counting, xcode4.5

I created a template project using the `create` in phonegap-2.7.0. This project would be non-ARC enabled and I wanted to convert it to ARC.

I went to **`Edit -> Refractor -> Convert to Objective-C ARC`** and *unselected* libCordova.a ([as mentioned here](http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2012/09/05/automatic-reference-counting-arc-and-cordova-plugins/) and in the [upgrade guide 2.0.0 to 2.0.1](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html)) and tried to convert to ARC. Everything compiled properly but I got this linker error in the end.

I'm using Xcode 4.5

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo:
>   can't figure out the architecture type of:
>   /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServerSockPG-cbdtpihmguyehtaqenaxuqiwkpyz/Build/Intermediates/ServerSockPG.build/Debug-iphoneos/ServerSockPG.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ServerSockPG
>   Command
>
> **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo
>   failed with exit code 1**

Pls guide me on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Go to Build Settings -> Architectures and make sure architecture selected is armv7, armv7s

Answer (score 0):

"ARC is available in Xcode 4.2 and upper version latest is XCODE 6.0  and only when compiling with Clang (a.k.a. "Apple LLVM compiler"). The setting is called, obviously enough, "Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting". Turn it on, and off you go.

If you're working on existing code, changing this setting will produce an enormous quantity of errors. ARC not only manages memory for you, but it forbids you from trying to do it yourself. It's illegal to manually send retain/release/autorelease when using ARC. Since normal non-ARC Cocoa code is littered with this stuff, you'll get a lot of errors.

Fortunately, Xcode offers a tool to convert existing code. Select Edit -> Refactor... -> Convert to Objective-C ARC... and Xcode will guide you through converting your code. Although there may be some situations where it needs help figuring out what to do, the process should be largely automatic."